# Organizing pointers array after realloc

Tags: c, realloc

I have created a dynamic list:

The struct is:

```
typedef struct{
    char *id;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    int age;
    char gender;
    char *username;
    char *password;
    char *description;
    char *hobbies;
}User;
```

And after I create User **headMan I add users via:

```
void newMan(User **headMan, int *size, char *id, char *name, char *surname,
            int age, char gender, char *username,
            char *password, char *description, char *hobbies){
    if(*size == 0){
        *headMan = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User));
        if(*headMan == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*headMan) -> id = (char*)malloc(ID_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> id == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> id failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> id,id);
        (*headMan) -> name = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> name == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> name failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> name,name);
        (*headMan) -> surname = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> surname == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> surname failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> surname, surname);
        (*headMan) -> age = age;
        (*headMan) -> gender = gender;

        (*headMan) -> username = (char*)malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> username == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> username failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> username, username);

        (*headMan) -> password = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> password == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> password failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> password, password);

        (*headMan) -> description = (char*)malloc(DESCRIPTION*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> description == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> description failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> description, description);

        (*headMan) -> hobbies = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if ((*headMan) -> hobbies == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of (*headMan) -> hobbies  failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy((*headMan) -> hobbies, hobbies);
        (*size)++;
    }
    else{
        headMan[*size] = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User));
        if(headMan[*size] == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        headMan[*size] -> id = (char*)malloc(ID_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> id == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> id failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> id,id);
        headMan[*size] -> name = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> name == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> name failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> name,name);
        headMan[*size] -> surname = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> surname == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> surname failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> surname, surname);
        headMan[*size] -> age = age;
        headMan[*size] -> gender = gender;

        headMan[*size] -> username = (char*)malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> username == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> username failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> username, username);

        headMan[*size] -> password = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> password == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> password failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> password, password);

        headMan[*size] -> description = (char*)malloc(DESCRIPTION*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> description == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> description failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> description, description);

        headMan[*size] -> hobbies = (char*)malloc(NAME_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        if (headMan[*size] -> hobbies == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of headMan[*size] -> hobbies  failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(headMan[*size] -> hobbies, hobbies);
        (*size)++;
    }

}
```

Now I move on the user list with an index for example headMan[i] now when I try to remove a user I use:

```
void removeMan(User** head, int* numberOfMen,char*  existUser){

    if ((strcmp(head[1] ->username,existUser) == 0)){
        freeUser(head[1]);
        free(head[1]);
        head = (User**)realloc(head, (*numberOfMen-1)*sizeof(User));
    }
    printListMen(head,numberOfMen);
}
```

When freeUser frees all the fields of the struct, now I can not understand how the realloc works.

If I have a list of 5 users and I remove the one in the 3rd place, using realloc will move the resize the list to 4? who will be listed in 3rd place?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). And `->` should be used without spaces around it, like the `.` operator

Answer (score 4):

`realloc()` only resizes the allocated block of memory, it doesn't move anything around.  You have to do that yourself.

So if you have your array looking like this:

```
{ A, B, C, D, E }
```

and you then remove `B`, it'll look like this:

```
{ A, empty, C, D, E }
```

You then have to move `C`, `D` and `E` so it looks like this:

```
{ A, C, D, E, empty }
```

Only then can you call `realloc()` to shrink it, so it looks like this:

```
{ A, C, D, E }
```

Two things to remember about `realloc()`:

1. When you shrink a block, whatever was in the space that was trimmed is lost forever.
2. When you expand a block, the contents of the newly expanded space are garbage.  Make sure you initialize before using.

In both cases, the original data that fits in the resized area are copied over.